# Wrap widget list not updating the list Flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I am working on flutter application and using the plugin reorderwrap to display me data.

https://pub.dev/packages/reorderwrap

This is the code in which i am creating the children of this widget using list.map().
Now I am trying to change the list(data) which i am passing to the above function (list.map()) to create child widgets but could not do so. The data on UI remains same and not changing. Can anyone please tell me what is the issue and how to solve it.

```html
class HotkeysMenuItemsWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final int count;
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> menuItems;

  HotkeysMenuItemsWidget({Key key, this.count, this.menuItems})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return HotkeysMenuItemsWidgetState();
  }
}

class HotkeysMenuItemsWidgetState extends State<HotkeysMenuItemsWidget> {
  List<Color> colorsCodes = [
    Color(0xffAEA2AE),
    Color(0xff9F9F5F),
    Color(0xff00838f),
    Color(0xffbcaaa4),
    Color(0xff795548),
    Color(0xffb39ddb),
    Color(0xffe57373),
    Color(0xff77AAA1),
    Color(0xffff8a80),
    Color(0xffB6AD7A),
    Color(0xffbcaaa4),
    Color(0xff26a69a),
    Color(0xffD6B07F),
    Color(0xffBF6666),
    Color(0xffBE91A2),
    Color(0xff7EB7AD),
    Color(0xffCD8C95),
    Color(0xff9fa8da),
    Color(0xfff48fb1),
    Color(0xff82b1ff),
    Color(0xff81c784),
    Color(0xff0277bd),
    Color(0xff9575cd),
    Color(0xff00796b),
    Color(0xfff06292),
  ];
  int menuIndex;
  List<Widget> cells = new List();
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> menuItemsList;
  ScrollController controller = new ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    print('CELL COUNT: ${widget.count}');
    menuIndex = 0;
    menuItemsList = widget.menuItems;
    super.initState();
  }

  Future modifierDialog() {
    return showGeneralDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: true,
      barrierLabel: MaterialLocalizations.of(context).modalBarrierDismissLabel,
      barrierColor: Colors.black45,
      transitionDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      pageBuilder: (BuildContext buildContext, Animation animation,
          Animation secondaryAnimation) {
        return Dialog(
          child: ModifiersDialogWidget(),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  changeMenuItems(list) {
    setState(() {
      menuItemsList = list;
    });
    print('NEW MENU LIST: $menuItemsList');
  }

  buildCells() {
    int index = -1;
    return menuItemsList.map((menuItem) {
      index++;
      if (menuIndex == colorsCodes.length - 1)
        menuIndex = 0;
      else
        menuIndex++;
      if (index == menuItemsList.length - 1) menuIndex = 0;
      return Material(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: Container(
          color: colorsCodes[menuIndex],
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.16,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.19,
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5, vertical: 5),
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 5),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Container(
                child: Text(
                  menuItem['name'],
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  maxLines: 2,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 18,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Icon(Icons.fastfood, size: 30, color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Container(
                //color: Colors.blue,
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        child: Text(
                          '\$4',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                        child: Material(
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                          child: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(
                              Icons.arrow_downward,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              size: 30,
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {
                              modifierDialog();
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: ReorderWrap(
          itemHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.20,
          itemWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.17,
          children: buildCells(),
          reorderCallback: (newIndexList, oldIndex, newIndex) {},
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the function in of parent widget from where I am calling changing the above widget state.

```html
 updateMenuItems(int catID) {
    Map<String, dynamic> category = categoriesList
        .firstWhere((element) => element['cat']['cat_id'] == catID);
    print('NEW LIST: ${category['items']}');
    menuItemsKey.currentState.changeMenuItems(category['items']);
  }
```

Comment: Hi There. Code screenshots are discouraged on Stackoverflow. Consider updating your post with valid code snippets. Also elaborate your query. What does it mean when `data on UI remains same` ? Are you updating something in `State` and Ui is not updating ? where is your `setState` call ?

Comment: Did some changes in my post. Please check now.

Comment: Where are you calling `changeMenuItems` and your `print('NEW MENU LIST: $menuItemsList');` will not print new list since `setState` is asynchronous, so you will see old data in console

Comment: I am calling this function from another widget and the console shows the new list but not on UI

Comment: Post full code of both the widgets

Comment: I have posted the code of child widget. And the code snippet of parent widget from where I am changing child widget state. Could not post the full code of parent widget, it is quite lengthy.